# how to give a result of select multiply case statement with group by without null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select a data by multiply case statement and sum a value in which case but it's need to group 2 column and result out like this

[image: Result of select case]

how to give a result without null and null

this is my query that gave this output in the picture
query :

```
select 
  expr1 as Custgroup, 
  case when YEAR(docdate) = '2013' then SUM(totalamount) else null end as '2013', 
  case when YEAR(docdate) = '2014' then SUM(totalamount) else null end as '2014', 
  case when YEAR(docdate) = '2015' then SUM(totalamount) else null end as '2015', 
  case when YEAR(docdate) = '2016' then SUM(totalamount) else null end as '2016', 
  case when YEAR(docdate) = '2017' then SUM(totalamount) else null end as '2017', 
  case when YEAR(docdate) = '2018' then SUM(totalamount) else null end as '2018' from NPHM56.dbo.arinvoiceview 
group by expr1, YEAR(docdate)
```

Comment: Great.  Now just show us some sample data which generated that output, and maybe someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move `case` expression inside `Sum` function and `group by expr1` like below

```
select 
  expr1 as Custgroup, 
  SUM(case when YEAR(docdate) = '2013' then totalamount else 0 end) as '2013',
  SUM(case when YEAR(docdate) = '2014' then totalamount else 0 end) as '2014',
  SUM(case when YEAR(docdate) = '2015' then totalamount else 0 end) as '2015',
  SUM(case when YEAR(docdate) = '2016' then totalamount else 0 end) as '2016',
  SUM(case when YEAR(docdate) = '2017' then totalamount else 0 end) as '2017',
  SUM(case when YEAR(docdate) = '2018' then totalamount else 0 end) as '2018'
  from NPHM56.dbo.arinvoiceview 
group by expr1
```

Comment: that's perfect the result is out like i want exactly thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use "sum" and "group by":

```
select Custgroup, sum([2013]) as [2013], sum([2014]) as [2014], ...
from (your query) as T
group by Custgroup
```

Comment: that's what i want thanks you the result out like i would be